# Examples on Javascript Object literal and prototype

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get indepth knowledge on object literal and prototypes? how they relate and differ and when to use? 
Is there any good websites and book which dives into indepth on object literal and prototype with plenty of examples etc?

Thanks

Comment: Any book on OO programming in Javascript should explain this.

Comment: There are many good resources listed in the [tag:javascript] [*info* page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) that should be able to help explain these.

Comment: All object created with object literals inherit from `Object.prototype`. I don't see any other relation between "literals" and "prototypes". Please clarify what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't really have a very strong relation.

- [Object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) or [initialisers](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5) are a feature of the language's syntax that can be used to create a `new Object` and set 0 or more properties with values.
- While a [`prototype`](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.5) is a particular object, or the [reference to that object](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.5), that new instances can be created to inherit from.

So, you could use one to create the other:

```
var prototype = {
    foo: function () {
        console.log('Hello');
    }
};

var instance = Object.create(prototype);
instance.foo(); // Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

[Found this on a Google search.](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

[**JavaScript: The Good Parts**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) by **Douglas Crockford** is a book you're looking for.